# Prevent create/update foreign key that refers to forbidden objects in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let us assume I have the following models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.TextField()
```

The problem is that creating a Post will let me set the blog id to anything (that exists). That means that I am able to create a Post object that has a relation to a `Blog` object that the user does not "own".

However, there are easy and documented ways to prevent the user from accessing objects via the `GET` method, that are forbidden to them, by filtering the queryset and using `check_object_permissions`. Example:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer = PostSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(blog__user=self.request.user)

def check_object_permissions(self, request, obj):
    if obj.user != request.user:
        raise exceptions.PermissionDenied()
    super().check_object_permissions(request, obj)
```

How do I solve my above issue and prevent creating relations to forbidden objects the smartest/correct way in Django REST framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add blog validation to the serializer (check [Field-level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) doc) and raise error if user dnt have permission to the selected blog:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def validate_blog(self, value):
        request = self.context['request']
        if value.user != request.user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Blog id doesn't exist')
        return value
```